# jQuery mobile icon count badges / bubbles

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

How to add a count bubble or badge on top of a icon (data-icon) in jQuery mobile. Is there a better way to add it as widget rather than manipulating with CSS ? I expect the count to be updated dynamically from the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML :

```
<span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-corner-all countBubl">12</span>
```

CSS :

```
.countBubl {float:left;margin-top:-42px;margin-left:35px;background:#ed1d24;color:#fff;padding:2px;}
```

Paste the HTML next to your image tag.
"You can adjust the margin-top & margin-left based on the icon size.I think it may work".
Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

Here's my version of a badge icon, easily tweakable by CSS (it assumes `border-radius` support):

```
.my-badge {
  display: none;
  background: #BA070F;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1px 7px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  top: -12px;
  z-index: 999;
  border-radius: .8em;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

It's hidden by default (`display: none`), and should be shown/hidden and the count updated programmatically as needed. Here's a simple example of how I'm doing it in jQuery, ymmv:

```
$('#badge-page1').html(++badgeCount).fadeIn();
```

I did this for use with a jQuery Mobile NavBar which is based on an unordered list. Here's an example of the markup for one tab, including the badge `span` I added that uses the above styles:

```
<li class="ui-badge-container">
  <span id="badge-page1" class="my-badge"></span>
  <a href="#page-tab1" data-role="tab">Tab 1</a>
</li>
```

Note that the badge is absolute positioned, so it must be in a container that is `position: relative`. I created a simple class to add to the containing element, in this case the parent `li` as seen above:

```
.ui-badge-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ey27uLr9/), slightly modified to work as a static example.

Comment: Way cleaner and simple solution, this should be the answer. Be aware using the class name `badge` with bootstrap has some effects. Keep that in mind.

Comment: @CesarBielich Great point -- I updated my example to avoid conflicts. Thanks!